# Cancel notifcation android samsung s6

Tags: android, android-notifications, samsung-mobile

I have problem with notification on samsung s6 edge phone with android 5.1.1
 I try cancel all notification when once appear on status bar, but is't work.
Please see my code:
I'm using NotificationListenerService. Access to notification enabled in system setting.

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    cancelAllNotifications();
}
```

On all clear google phone sdk it's works. But on samsung s6 do nothing when execute that code. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I would try to use `getActiveNotifications()` and delete every single notification by hand.

Comment: are you using look sdk?

Comment: have log in this method first does this methods calling?

Comment: @kiturk3 using samsung native sdk